# Como hacer una petición HTTP asincrónica en Swift

Tags: ios, swift, http-post, requests, asynctask

Estoy haciendo peticiones sincrónicas con semáforos, pero apenas le doy tap a una notificación desde background me sale este error debes en cuando:

> 021-10-08 10:09:56.126936-0500 [3430:753800]
> [connection] nw_write_request_report [C4] Send failed with error
> "Socket is not connected" 2021-10-08 10:09:56.129875-0500
> [3430:753800] Task
> <1CDC044B-CB5F-4B75-9FEA-9D521DC9960E>.<7> HTTP load failed, 36/0
> bytes (error code: -1005 [1:53]) 2021-10-08 10:09:56.134175-0500
> [3430:754147] Task
> <1CDC044B-CB5F-4B75-9FEA-9D521DC9960E>.<7> finished with error [-1005]
> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was
> lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x281264db0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
> Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1CDC044B-CB5F-4B75-9FEA-9D521DC9960E>.<7>,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> "LocalDataTask <1CDC044B-CB5F-4B75-9FEA-9D521DC9960E>.<7>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.,
> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://........,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https:........,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1} Synchronous task ended with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, NSUnderlyingError=0x281264db0
> {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},
> _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1CDC044B-CB5F-4B75-9FEA-9D521DC9960E>.<7>,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> "LocalDataTask <1CDC044B-CB5F-4B75-9FEA-9D521DC9960E>.<7>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.,
> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://...........,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://............,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
class HttpClient{

    public func sentRequest(url: String, json: Data?){
        let url = URL(string: url)
        guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = json
        let (data, _, error) = URLSession.shared.synchronousDataTask(urlrequest: request)
        if let error = error {
            print("Synchronous task ended with error: \(error)")
        }
        else if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Synchronous task ended without errors.")
            print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
        }
    }
}

extension URLSession {
    func synchronousDataTask(urlrequest: URLRequest) -> (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        var data: Data?
        var response: URLResponse?
        var error: Error?

        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: Int(0.2))

        let dataTask = self.dataTask(with: urlrequest) {
            data = $0
            response = $1
            error = $2

            semaphore.signal()
        }
        dataTask.resume()

        _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)

        return (data, response, error)
    }
}
```

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo asincrónico para que no pase esto desde una clase o otra forma de implementación?

Comment: Por qué no usas las funciones asíncronas que ya tiene `URLSession`? Según el código, estás agregando tu propia función.

Comment: @Bicho, ya lo hice así y me ayudo, gracias.